# Why are the Bad Girls the only defenders of the Bronze Dimension?

Tags: angel-n-devil

In the show *Angel 'N Devil*, The Avatar of Light, Xiong Ya, makes pacts with the Bad Girls (a group of teenagers) to defend the Bronze Dimension. They seem to be the main line of defense against supernatural evil entities, at least in their region and counting out dimensionally traveling demon hunters. It seems like governmental entities, such as the police, only deal with mundane criminals. However, why?

It's not because only teenagers can use powers, because we've seen adults with powers who aren't Daycrawlers or Nightcrawlers, such as A-Tien Wang, who seemed to have a strong aura. It's not because they're the strongest, since we've seen people like Charlie Wang with a high destructive power and even weapons that don't seem to come from a pact with Xiong Ya.

So why is it only the Bad Girls who defend the Bronze Dimension? Why did Xiong Ya choose only teenagers specifically to make pacts with, and why don't any of the other people with combat powers seemingly defend the Bronze Dimension more officially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The show doesn't seem to make it clear, but there seems to be some kind of loose  masquerade, probably more willful than otherwise. Various statements, at one point or another, suggest that the nature of the supernatural creatures of Bronze Dimension is not common knowledge. At various times, the characters try to avoid talking about the existence of evil creatures in front of "Muggles." Victims of the Daycrawlers and Nightcrawlers don't remember what happened to them, and their activities are sometimes dismissed as mundane. As such, much of the population may not really be aware enough of what's going on to do anything about it.

However, this concealment seems to be fairly loose, given that people are aware of the existence of the Bad Girls, and of the villains that they fight, and that at a Bad-Girls-themed costume party people dress up as vampires. Further, when at least one character discovers that they're an Energy User, with supernatural powers, they're not particularly shocked by this fact; nor do most characters avoid using their powers in public. Thus, it seems like most people are intentionally staying out of the whole business of combating evil creatures. But why?

That brings us, however, to the second point.  Most of the non-evil supernatural creatures of Bronze Dimension seem to be members of, or associated with, the royal families of the Pureblood Daycrawlers and the Energy Users. Given the extreme deference shown to the members of the Triad, and the assertion of "Gabriel" that A-Tien Wang and the Principal have been in control of the world since the extermination of the Pureblood Nightcrawlers, **they could well be the actual powers behind the scenes in Bronze Dimension,** which explains why the authorities stay well away from supernatural matters. And they don't seem to have much interest in  controlling Daycrawlers or Nightcrawlers, except insofar as the latter interfere with their own agenda.

Although we don't know the actual size or nature of Bronze Dimension, almost everyone we've seen with a half-way respectable Destructive Power has either been a member of a group specifically brought together by a member of the royal family of Purebred Daycrawlers (the Bad Girls), a member of the royal family of energy users, or a Crawler of some type themselves, or possibly not even from the Bronze Dimension (Kou Chi). It seems like random Energy Users walking around capable of taking on Crawlers, and whose powers have been activated, are not very common.

**So the powers that be in the setting actually have the power to deal with the evil creatures to an extent, but aren't too interested, and average people who can do so are few and far between; in addition, information about the nature of the supernatural threats is probably intentionally not widely publicized.**